# Reading gzip files in nimlang?

Tags: zip, gzip, nim-lang

I've been trying to learn nimlang because it seems like it has a lot of potential to integrate with python simply - but I'm a windows guy.  The script I'm trying to compile is a simple one:

```
import zip/gzipfiles  # Import zip package

block:
  let vcf = newGzFileStream("test.txt.gz")  # Open gzip file
  var line: string  # Declare line variable

  # Loop over each line in the file
  while not vcf.atEnd():
    line = vcf.readLine()
    echo line
```

Using a test file that I've gzipped called 'test.txt.gz':

```
this
is
gzipped
```

It compiles successfully on windows linux subsystem, and regular linux:

```
bub@bubs-surface-book-2:/mnt/c/Users/bubth/Development/nim$ nim c read_gzip.nim
Hint: used config file '/etc/nim.cfg' [Conf]
Hint: system [Processing]
Hint: read_gzip [Processing]
Hint: gzipfiles [Processing]
Hint: os [Processing]
Hint: strutils [Processing]
Hint: parseutils [Processing]
Hint: math [Processing]
Hint: algorithm [Processing]
Hint: times [Processing]
Hint: posix [Processing]
Hint: ospaths [Processing]
Hint: zlib [Processing]
Hint: streams [Processing]
CC: read_gzip
Hint:  [Link]
Hint: operation successful (22504 lines compiled; 0.634 sec total; 35.035MiB peakmem; Debug Build) [SuccessX]
bub@bubs-surface-book-2:/mnt/c/Users/bubth/Development/nim$ ./read_gzip
asdf
1234
test
this
works
bub@bubs-surface-book-2:/mnt/c/Users/bubth/Development/nim$
```

But on windows, it compiles but then doesn't know how to use the zlib dll:

```
PS C:\Users\bubth\Development\nim> nim c .\read_gzip.nim
Hint: used config file 'C:\Users\bubth\scoop\apps\nim\current\config\nim.cfg' [Conf]
Hint: system [Processing]
Hint: widestrs [Processing]
Hint: io [Processing]
Hint: read_gzip [Processing]
Hint: gzipfiles [Processing]
Hint: os [Processing]
Hint: strutils [Processing]
Hint: parseutils [Processing]
Hint: math [Processing]
Hint: bitops [Processing]
Hint: macros [Processing]
Hint: algorithm [Processing]
Hint: unicode [Processing]
Hint: pathnorm [Processing]
Hint: osseps [Processing]
Hint: winlean [Processing]
Hint: dynlib [Processing]
Hint: times [Processing]
Hint: options [Processing]
Hint: typetraits [Processing]
Hint: time_t [Processing]
Hint: zlib [Processing]
Hint: streams [Processing]
Hint:  [Link]
Hint: operation successful (37181 lines compiled; 0.921 sec total; 46.852MiB peakmem; Debug Build) [SuccessX]
PS C:\Users\bubth\Development\nim> .\read_gzip.exe
could not load: zlib1.dll
PS C:\Users\bubth\Development\nim>
```

I've tried installing zlib via https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg but even after walking through and successfully "linking" things, it's not finding the libraries.  I swear I'm not stupid, but what am I missing?  Is there some special way to get those packages onto windows in a way that nimble will recognize?

Comment: Do you have zlib1.dll in your PATH or the local directory where the EXE is? If not, you need to download a copy. If you do, you need to make sure that it is the same arch as the EXE.

Comment: I guess I assumed vcpkg would do that for me, but I may have been mistaken.  I'll try and give that a go - Is this just a "windows doesn't put those in PATH by default but linux does" kind of thing?

Comment: Tried adding a copy into the local folder and to PATH and still getting the same error.

Comment: What's your Nim arch? nim -v. And then check if the dll matches.

Comment: It looks like zip package assumes that you have the dll installed if you're on windows, and doesn't include it.  To fix this, I had to manually download the "correct" .dll file and add it to my path, after which it compiled and ran just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like zip package assumes that you have the dll installed if you're on windows, and doesn't include it.  To fix this, I had to manually download the correct .dll file and add it to my path, after which it compiled and ran just fine.

```
PS C:\Users\bubth\Development\vcpkg> .\vcpkg.exe install zlib:x64-windows
Computing installation plan...
The following packages are already installed:
    zlib[core]:x64-windows
Package zlib:x64-windows is already installed

Total elapsed time: 618.1 us

The package zlib is compatible with built-in CMake targets:

    find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ZLIB::ZLIB)

PS C:\Users\bubth\Development\vcpkg>
```

Added the vcpkg bin folder to my Path environment variable

```
C:\Users\bubth\Development\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\bin
```

Recompiled and it ran:

```
PS C:\Users\bubth\Development\nim> nim c --run .\read_gzip.nim
Hint: used config file 'C:\Users\bubth\scoop\apps\nim\current\config\nim.cfg' [Conf]
Hint: system [Processing]
Hint: widestrs [Processing]
Hint: io [Processing]
Hint: read_gzip [Processing]
Hint: gzipfiles [Processing]
Hint: os [Processing]
Hint: strutils [Processing]
Hint: parseutils [Processing]
Hint: math [Processing]
Hint: bitops [Processing]
Hint: macros [Processing]
Hint: algorithm [Processing]
Hint: unicode [Processing]
Hint: pathnorm [Processing]
Hint: osseps [Processing]
Hint: winlean [Processing]
Hint: dynlib [Processing]
Hint: times [Processing]
Hint: options [Processing]
Hint: typetraits [Processing]
Hint: time_t [Processing]
Hint: zlib [Processing]
Hint: streams [Processing]
Hint:  [Link]
Hint: operation successful (37182 lines compiled; 1.361 sec total; 58.07MiB peakmem; Debug Build) [SuccessX]
Hint: C:\Users\bubth\Development\nim\read_gzip.exe  [Exec]
asdf
1234
test
this
works
PS C:\Users\bubth\Development\nim>
```

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the zip nimble package, which I presume you are using, [seems to be a wrapper](https://github.com/nim-lang/zip/blob/master/zip/zlib.nim#L3) around the zlib found at https://www.zlib.net. From there you have a few windows links which might contain the `.dll` file you need, particularly promising looks the [zlib for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm) website.

If you keep having problems with this module you could try [creating an issue at the GitHub project](https://github.com/nim-lang/zip), that README could really have a few links to binary downloads of the `.dll` you need.

Comment: added a comment to a current issue that had some suggestions that didn't work - it looks like the library assumes that you have zlib.dll in your path already, which for a vanilla install of windows is not true.  

Personally I'm of the opinion that the installation should validate that the required packages are there - but I don't know if there's something more idiomatic that I'm missing with how nim is supposed to install packages